# Splitting web-app and mobile-app request in Yii2

Tags: json, mobile, yii2, request, response

I created a restful web-app platform using yii2 framework. It is working with no problems using a browser. Now I'm developing a mobile-app with angular and ionic and I'm searching for some guide to help me splitting the request from browser and app. Using the browser the web-app is configured to have a html view response, how can I detect a mobile-app request to change response in JSON format in each controller/action?

It's my first mobile-app development.

Answer (score 0):

I just fighted this same war this week and I ended up splitting the folders and generating a new yii-app with fresh controllers just for the api.

I tried creating the api folder inside the web backend project, but I had to much problems with redirections, and as I was working from Android emulator fueled by Expo it was almost impossible to reach the api inside my localhost from outside.

At the end in the API REST you just reuse the database connection, rest of files are new. So there is no much to win in placing it in the same folder/project.

By the way, read this documentation:  [Implementing RESTful Web Service APIs in Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start)

As a code example you could check my yii2 web app: https://github.com/jvidalv/fempoble

And the api that works with the web: https://github.com/jvidalv/api-fempoble

Comment: I think that the best way is to add a parameter in request, for example {"mobile" : 1} and check:
`if ($request->mobile) 
$response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;`

Comment: @Katalux that is ugly and not very escalable. My advice, read the api restful guide and build it clean using yii2 default implementation.